# mySQL: Is it possible to make a SELECT statement, when the value in the DB is seperated with commas?

Tags: mysql, select

MY DB entry for the field data in the table productinfo is this for example:

```
66523,665893,745896321
```

Now I want a `SELECT` statement which gives me the hole entry:

For example:

```
SELECT * from productinfo WHERE products="66523"
```

Comment: This seems to be a surprisingly common practice. If you don't store raw data in your database, you can't benefit from database features. You're basically using your DB as an overcomplicated file system ;-)

Comment: You should normalize your database, so you can do a simple join, instead of building work arounds.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from productinfo where FIND_IN_SET ('66523', products);
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bad0c/3)

Comment: @Praveen +1 Ohh.. I remember using this function for my recent project. It didn't came to my mind. Perfecto! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM   productinfo
WHERE  Concat(',', products, ',') LIKE '%,66523,%'
```

In [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bad0c/1), you can check that the first three rows are returned because they contain the 66523 product, but not the 4th one, which contain a product number *containing* 66523.

But it's a **really bad habit** to store more than one piece of data into one single field. You should preferably split this data into a new table, using foreign keys. Otherwise, you will be stuck with similar workarounds, without any efficient way to use indexes, and therefore low performances.

Comment: I thought about this, biut there can be also a number that is like this: 66523324234, so the searchstring is IN this number, but teh wrong product!

Comment: Added ',' around the product field, this way you're sure to match the right number.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
SELECT * from productinfo WHERE products like "66523,%" OR  products like ",66523,%" OR  products like "%,66523"
```

It will match anything containing `66523, + something.` OR `, + 66523, + something.` OR `something + 66523`(last number).  It will make sure that whole number is matched.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a923/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
SELECT * from productinfo WHERE products like "66523,%" OR products like  "%,66523,%" OR products like  "%,66523" or products="66523";
```

Comment: What if the list has no commas, only one number 66523 in it?

Comment: @BillKarwin in that case need one more `OR` condition, see my updated answer. This will work, but I am not sure, this a best solution, as this query is too long.